# WordPress And Database

Tags: wordpress

A few days ago for some reasons I uninstalled my Xampp which containing my WordPress projects database in localhost . Now I need that database . But when I run localhost/wordpress/
in my localhost it says that Object not found!. So how can I solve that problem. I want to regain my database . I have all the contented having in the htdocts folder. Please help me someone.

Comment: Your database has nothing to do with your files. I hope you have a backup, else you should rebuild everything.

Comment: What kind of back up Bondye .

Comment: A backup of your database. Your pages, posts, settings etc are stored in the database. With a clean wordpress installation, you lose all these settings.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall process of the `xampp` system most probably will keep the existing MySQL databases. You can try accessing `phpMyAdmin` after re-installation of `xampp`, for example, and see if the old Wordpress database exists.

If old database exists, check in your folder `wordpress` for the config file and change the variables, which are responsible for database connection, open your `wp-config.php` file and edit the appropriate values, for example look for those values:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'wordpress');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'wordpress');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

Also, one note - having `htdocs` folder does not mean anything in database terms, the MySQL databases are stored in different location, this is usually the folder `<your_xampp_install_folder>/mysql/data`.

Answer (score 0):

Also in addition to bodi0 You should find the database folder in /mysql/data/ if your database name was mydb the folder name will be /mydb/ then put it in your current MySQL server's /data/ directory. After that just update wp-config.php like has been mentioned by bodi0